# Dart - Nested Class using Map<String, String>

Tags: dart

im newbie in flutter/dart and currently stuck on generating Map on nested json.

This is my object to hold the value but i dont know how to do nested object.

```
>      Map<String, String> _signupData = {
>         "userName":  '',
>         "email": '',
>         "password": '',
>         "confirmpassword": '',
>         // not sure what's next 
>       };
```

What i am trying to achieve.

```
{
    "userName": "ColeCash",
    "email": "cashcole@xforce.com",
    "password": "password",
    "confirmpassword": "password",
    "activityId": "1020",
    "Roles": ["User"],
    "UserInfo": 
        {
        "firstName": "Cole",
        "lastName": "Cash",
        "address1": "Manchester Hills   ",
        "mobilePrefix": "+11",
        "mobileNo": "8280410"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dynamic` like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
  "userName": "ColeCash",
  "email": "cashcole@xforce.com",
  "password": "password",
  "confirmpassword": "password",
  "activityId": "1020",
  "Roles": ["User"],
  "UserInfo": {
    "firstName": "Cole",
    "lastName": "Cash",
    "address1": "Manchester Hills   ",
    "mobilePrefix": "+11",
    "mobileNo": "8280410",
  }
};
```